# Jquery Delay when value is removed from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dropdown look when the value is Removed

[image]

I have been trying to remove a value from the dropdown when a user clicks on the drop.But there is some delay in that and also when removed it shows a blank area below the last dropdown value.

Here is the code i have used.

```
jq(document).ready(function()
{
   jq('#gbMainTable').on('click', 'tr.dr td[name="v4"] select', function() 
   { 
     jq('#gbMainTable tr.dr td[name="v4"] select').find('option[value=Other]').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: If this isn't a standard `<select/>` element then you'll have to supply enough code for us to see this in action.  Edit the question and use a snippet to add working code.

Comment: It is a standard select statement,the thing is I dont have the control of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (often ?), native JS si more simple & efficient :

**HTML :**

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>
    <option value="hey">hey</option>
</select>
```

**JS :**

```
function removeOption(value) {

    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var optionToRemove = document.querySelector('#test option[value="' + value + '"]');
        if (optionToRemove) {
            this.removeChild(optionToRemove);
        }
    });
}

removeOption('other');
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/nejktxso/**

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these to remove accordingly

```
$("#selectBox option[value='other']").remove();
```

---

```
$('#some_select_box').click(function() {
  $('option:selected', this).remove();
});
```